# Are all Distance Metrics, Divergence Functions?

Tags: metric-spaces, divergence-operator

Quite simply, as the question states. Are all distance metrics, divergence functions? The wikipedia defintion for a divergence function is given as

> Suppose S is a space of all probability distributions with common
>   support. Then a divergence on S is a function D(· || ·): S×S → R
>   satisfying
>
> D(p || q) ≥ 0 for all p, q ∈ S, D(p || q) = 0 if and only if p = q,

**https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_(statistics)**

whilst the distance metric definition (**https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)**) given is similar with the addition of requiring symmetry and abiding of the triangle inequality.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

If $d$ is a distance metric on $S$ then $d$ is a divergence on $S$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a metric on a space of probability distributions with common support is, a fortiori, a divergence.